# How to back up local (downloaded) music from iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, music

I'm facing a problem. I have around 2 GB of music (nearly 100 songs) stored on my iPhone. Now I need to clean them up and keep around 5 my most favorite songs only. But I want to back up them somewhere first for just in case in the future if I change my mind.

I know how to back up photos and videos from iPhone to Google Drive, Google Photos and to my computer. But I don't know how to do the same things to music. Does anyone know any solution please? Thanks.

Comment: How did you get the songs onto your phone and in which app do you play them?

Comment: I can't remember exactly but previously they were in my sim card when I was using my Android Samsung phone. Then when I switched to iPhone, I attached my sim to it and that's how they're in my iPhone.

Comment: Which app do you use to play them?

Comment: Apple Music app. It was installed at the time I bought my iPhone and I've been using it ever since.

Comment: I‘m quite sure that the Music app can‘t play music files from other locations, including SIM cards (and I‘m not sure SIM cards have enough space to even store 2 GB of music files), so we seem to miss some details here. Is your mobile carrier offering this as part of the subscription?

Comment: ok I'm finally able to backup my music files using this tool https://www.easeus.com/phone-transfer/mobimover-free.html. I can't remember how did my music ended up there. Maybe the shop where I bought my iPhone copied my music into it.